# Help adding to formula

Tags: formula

I need to add logic to this formula, to add "IF (texcellency__DefHC_NumEmployees__c **OR custom_number_field__c** < 2749, "Small", IF ( texcellency__DefHC_NumEmployees__c **OR custom_number_field__c** > 10999, "Large","Medium"))

Current actual formula:

```
IF(
    texcellency__DefHC_NumEmployees__c < 2749, 
    "Small",
    IF(
        texcellency__DefHC_NumEmployees__c > 10999, 
        "Large", 
        "Medium"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparisons can't be chained like what you've tried

```java
/* this is wrong */
texcellency__DefHC_NumEmployees__c OR custom_number_field__c < 2749
```

Instead, you need to do each comparison explicitly. You then wrap them in an `OR()` function (to get the "X or Y" that you're looking for).

```java
/* This is correct */
OR(texcellency__DefHC_NumEmployees__c < 2749, custom_number_field__c < 2749)
```

Apply the same thing to your inner `IF()`

Instead of wrapping them in an `OR()`, you could use the infix `||` operator (`1 < 2 || 2 > 3` is equivalent to `OR(1 < 2, 2 > 3)`), but I prefer to use `OR()` and `AND()` by default because it's harder to mess up if your logic gets a little more complex.
Whatever approach you end up choosing, just be sure to be consistent (mixing styles is harder to read, harder to maintain, and more prone to errors).